# Is this a correct way to create a read-only view of a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to create a read-only reference to a NumPy array.  Is this a correct way to make `b` a read-only reference to `a` (`a` is any NumPy array)?

```
def get_readonly_view(a):
    b = a.view()
    b.flags.writeable = False
    return b
```

Specifically, I would like to ensure the above does not 'copy' the contents of `a`?  (I tried testing this with `np.shares_memory` and it does return `True`.  But I am not sure if that is a correct test.)

In addition I wonder if `get_readonly_view` is already implemented in NumPy?

---

**Update.**   It has been suggested to turn the array to a class property to make it read-only.  I think this does not work:

```
import numpy as np

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = np.arange(15).reshape((3, 5))


    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a


    def bar(self):
        print(self._a)
```

But the client can change contents of `_a`:

```
>> baz = Foo()
>> baz.bar()
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
>> baz.a[1, 2] = 10
>> baz.bar()
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6 10  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

while I would like `baz.a[1, 2] = 10` to raise an exception.

Comment: The first thing that pops into my head is to make the array a class property, using the `@property` decorator.  These are read-only.

Comment: @S3DEV I don't think that would work.  You can still write into the array even if it is a class property.  (See the update.)

Comment: `a.view()` works, but the usual way to get a view of an array would be `a[:]`. Other than that, this is pretty much what I would write.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks.  Do you happen to know if there is a built-in function in NumPy to create the read-only view?   (It's not a big deal to write one like what I wrote, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.)

Comment: I think your way is pretty straightforward. Some functions, like [`as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html), can give you a read-only view, so you could do for example `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, a.shape, a.strides, writeable=False)`, but I think I'd prefer the way you posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach seems to be the suggested way of creating a [read-only](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html#numpy-ndarray-flags) [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy-ndarray-view).

In particular, `arr.view()` (which can also be written as a slicing `arr[:]`) will create a reference to `arr`, while modifying the `writeable` flag is the suggested way of making a NumPy array read-only.

The documentation also provides some additional information on the inheritance of the `writeable` property:

> The data area can be written to. Setting this to False locks the data, making it read-only. A view (slice, etc.) inherits WRITEABLE from its base array at creation time, but a view of a writeable array may be subsequently locked while the base array remains writeable. (The opposite is not true, in that a view of a locked array may not be made writeable. However, currently, locking a base object does not lock any views that already reference it, so under that circumstance it is possible to alter the contents of a locked array via a previously created writeable view onto it.) Attempting to change a non-writeable array raises a RuntimeError exception.

Just to reiterate and inspect what is going on:

```
import numpy as np


def get_readonly_view(arr):
    result = arr.view()
    result.flags.writeable = False
    return result


a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = get_readonly_view(a)

print(a.flags)
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : False
#   OWNDATA : True
#   WRITEABLE : True
#   ALIGNED : True
#   WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
print(b.flags)
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : False
#   OWNDATA : False
#   WRITEABLE : False
#   ALIGNED : True
#   WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False

print(a.base)
# None
print(b.base)
# [[0. 0.]
#  [0. 0.]]

a[1, 1] = 1.0
# ...works
b[0, 0] = 1.0
# raises  ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```